# How to do specific MySQL calculations depending on the column value?

Tags: mysql, math

Is there a way to multiply a column with a predefined number based on another column? There are multiple predefined numbers that are used depending on the value in the column.

Example:

Table

```
Columns: persons_id,activity,scale
```

Values

```
1,swimming,4  
1,baseball,2  
1,basketball,3  
2,swimming,6  
2,basketball,3
```

If my predefined numbers are: 6 (swimming), 8 (baseball), 5 (basketball)

The output would look like this

```
1,swimming,4,24  
1,baseball,2,16  
1,basketball,2,10  
2,swimming,6,36  
2,basketball,3,15
```

Edit: Thank you everyone for contributing. I ended up using the solution from sgeddes.

Comment: Are these multipliers also stored in the database?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use `CASE`:

```
SELECT Persons_Id, Activity, Scale, 
   Scale * 
   CASE 
      WHEN Activity = 'swimming' THEN 6
      WHEN Activity = 'baseball' THEN 8
      WHEN Activity = 'basketball' THEN 5
      ELSE 1
   END Total
FROM YourTable
```

Good luck.

Comment: +1 Although, in your example, "CASE Activity WHEN 'swimming' THEN 6.." would be tidier

Comment: @dai -- No problem, glad I could.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Have another column called WEIGHT that multiples the SCALE value.  Perhaps you can calculate the product using a trigger to populate the column.  Otherwise, a simple SELECT will do fine.

Comment: The weight is based on the users preference so I prefer avoiding an additional column. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this query:

```
select persons_id, activity, scale, 
 scale * case when activity = 'swimming' then 6
              when activity = 'baseball' then 8
              when activity = 'basketball' then 5 end as result
from Table1
```

but a better solution will be defining a new table Coefficients(activity, coefficient)

so that you can insert rows:
'swimming', 6
'baseball', 8
'basketball', 5

then use something like this:

```
select persons_id, activity, scale, scale * coefficient as result
from Table1 inner join Coefficients on Table1.activity = Coefficients.activity
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a table that stores the value or create a subquery that will return the multipliers:

```
select persons_id,
  t.activity,
  scale, 
  scale * s.val  as result
from yourtable t
inner join
(
  select 'swimming' activity, 6 val
  union all
  select 'baseball' activity, 8 val
  union all
  select 'basketball' activity, 5 val
) s
  on t.activity = s.activity
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/71541/2)

The result is:

```
| PERSONS_ID |   ACTIVITY | SCALE | RESULT |
--------------------------------------------
|          1 |   swimming |     4 |     24 |
|          1 |   baseball |     2 |     16 |
|          1 | basketball |     3 |     15 |
|          2 |   swimming |     6 |     36 |
|          2 | basketball |     3 |     15 |
```